# Parsing unnamed JSON arrays within array with Restkit

Tags: json, restkit, key-value-coding

I have the following JSON body containing arrays of decimal numbers within arrays:

( I. )

```
{
"decimals":
  [
     [
        18000.00,
        18000.00
     ]
  ],
}
```

I have created a class `DecimalEntity` with helper attribute "`number`" (`NSDecimalNumber`) and recursive relationship "`numbers`" (1-many relationship). Also this variant is possible:

( II. )

```
 {
    "decimals":
         [
            18000.00,
            18000.00
         ],
    }
```

How can I setup the mapping of the `DecimalEntity` so that it parses the above `JSON` bodies? I have setup the property mapping for "`number`" which works for (II.) but it does not work for (I.) That is why I've created the relationship between the `DecimalEntity` and "`numbers`" using

```
RKPropertyMapping* decimalEntityPropertyMapping =
                              [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil
                                                                          toKeyPath:@"numbers"
                                                                        withMapping:decimalEntityMapping];
```

and added this `decimalEntityPropertyMapping` back in `decimalEntityMapping` to create a recursive relationship:

```
[decimalEntityMapping                        addPropertyMapping:decimalEntityPropertyMapping];
```

But this variant crashes with `**[NSNull hasPrefix:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Also I tried to flatten the arrays using `@unionOfArrays` but I do not know how to use it.
    `[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"@unionOfArrays": @"numbers" }];` ?

Thank you for a hint.

## **UPDATE:**

I'm trying to do it in a conventional way, because it should work I think. I have changed the structure and the relationship of my classes (NSManagedObject subclasses):

DecimalEntityArray: 
  contains a helper relationship 1-M to DecimalEntity's:"decimals"

DecimalEntity:
  contains a helper attribute of the type Decimal: "number"

The class DecimalEntityArray is mapped to the outer brackets and the DecimalEntity to inner brackets:

```
"arrayOfArrays":
  [ >>>>> 1-M, DecimalEntityArray
     [ >>>>> 1-M, DecimalEntity
        18000.00,
        18000.00
     ]
  ],
```

Mapping setup looks like this:

```
// setting up the attribute mappings:
RKObjectMapping* decimalEntityMapping               = 
    [DecimalEntity mappingForStore:managedObjectStore];
RKObjectMapping* decimalEntityArrayMapping          = 
    [DecimalEntityArray mappingForStore:managedObjectStore];

// the **nil** value denotes the fact that there is no dictionary, 
// just a direct mapping to NSSet of DecimalEntity's  
RKPropertyMapping* decimalEntityPropertyMapping =
              [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil
                                                          toKeyPath:@"decimals"
                                                        withMapping:decimalEntityMapping];

// setup the relationship between DecimalEntityArray and its DecimalEntity's 
[decimalEntityArrayMapping   addPropertyMapping:decimalEntityPropertyMapping];


// finally setup the relation between the outermost json attribute, "arrayOfArrays" 
// and DecimalEntityArray
RKPropertyMapping* decimalEntityArrayPropertyMappingPotentialWin =
    [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"potentionalWin"
                                                toKeyPath:@"potentionalWin"
                                              withMapping:decimalEntityArrayMapping];
```

But this solution crashes with **[NSNull hasPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance** and a suggestion

***Mapping one to many relationship value at keyPath 'arrayOfArrays' to 'arrayOfArrays'*** ...
***WARNING: Detected a relationship mapping for a collection containing another collection. This is probably not what you want. Consider using a KVC collection operator (such as @unionOfArrays) to flatten your mappable collection.***

*This is probably not what you want.* But that is really what I want. So this conventional way does not work? I guess I am a step from getting it correct.

**[NSNull hasPrefix:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance** originates from the definition of decimalEntityPropertyMapping, where the KeyPath == nil. The strange thing is the nil value is allowed according the documentation:

*sourceKeyPath:*
*A key path from which to retrieve data in the source object representation that is to be mapped as a relationship. If `nil`, then the mapping is performed directly against the parent object representation.*

Comment: Do you have control of the source JSON? Have you looked at using a dynamic mapping?

Comment: Thank you Wain. No I can not change the way it is being sent to the client. (although I do my best to push the change because every client has to do some sort of trickery to parse it at the moment, but chance the api will change is really small).

I am considering using a proxy object which would parse the host array and it would contain a 1-M relationship to DecimalNumber/or a new class containing decimal number.

I will check the dynamic mapping http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKDynamicMapping.html

Comment: Dynamic mapping should help, possibly also with a collection operator like `@unionOfArrays` when you find an array of arrays.

Comment: I have updated the question with my rogue solution. It works. Interestingly without side effects. What about to add a new meta property @self which would direct the mapping engine to map directly the unnamed json field to the relationshop?

Comment: Add your solution as an answer so you can accept it. The @self question is better asked as a github issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION

I have checked the issue with debugger (adding symbolic exception with the symbol *-[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:]*) and added the line *if([keyPath isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) return YES;* in **RKMappingOperation.m** and it works smoothly with the above mapping defined:

```
// Returns YES if there is a value present for at least one key path in the given collection
static BOOL RKObjectContainsValueForKeyPaths(id representation, NSArray *keyPaths)
{
    for (NSString *keyPath in keyPaths) {
        if([keyPath isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) return YES;
        if ([representation valueForKeyPath:keyPath]) return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```